# generate poisson distribution using R

Tags: r

I need to generate poisson distribution of different lambda contained in a vector(length of 50), use the result as a new vector of lambda and then do it for 10 times repeatedly. I know I can do it with `for` but it seems lousy. Is there any good techs?
BTW: `rpois(50, seq(1,10))` seems not working.

Comment: try to read `?rpois`

Comment: What doesn't work? Why do you assume that `rpois` isn't working? Before assuming that a function call used by most R programmers is wrong, you should check your code and probably any assumptions

Comment: Sorry I type it wrong in r, I will delete this question in 5mins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
library(plyr)
list_poisson <- lapply(seq(1:10), FUN = function(x, y) rpois(y, x), y = 50)
```

To generate a list of poisson distributions with different lambda